# PHP - how to use a variables that inside an if statement without using global

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to pull out two variables values out from a function without no need to use global and of course we are going to use this function at another page.

```
function get_selected_page() {
    if (isset($_GET['subj'])) {
        $sel_subject = get_subject_by_id($_GET['subj']);
        $sel_page = NULL;
    } elseif (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $sel_page = get_page_by_id($_GET['page']);
        $sel_subject = NULL;
    } else {
        $sel_subject = NULL;
        $sel_page = NULL;
    }
}
```

The variables are $sel_subject and $sel_page

Comment: return them in an array(). `return array($sel_subject,$sel_page);`

Answer (score 0):

You can return them from your function, inside an array:

```
return array(
    'sel_page' => $sel_page,
    'sel_subject' => $sel_subject
);
```

Then use it like:

```
$vars = get_selected_page();
echo $vars['sel_page'];
```

Comment: actually it doesn't work because i don't want to echo the variable i just want it not give me an error and when I'm catching the value of the function. So using array isn't the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions:

```
<?php

$f = function () {
        $_SESSION['one'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['two'] = 2;
};

$f();

extract($_SESSION);

echo $one, $two;
```

Or references:

```
<?php

// $one = $two = 0;

$f = function (&$one, &$two) {
        $one = 1;
        $two = 2;
};

$f($one, $two);

echo $one, $two;
```

Comment: i don't want to echo variables i want to use the whole function as it's. but when i use it. it gave me an errors because they can't not define the variables. so all i want to defined the value to the page. again defined not catching.